# Sum notation, if the sum is from an index to the same index, is it equal to $0$ or the first term?

Tags: notation

Say we have $\sum\limits^n_{i=1} 1$

Say $n=1$: is this sum $1$ or $0$?

Comment: It is $1$.  In general $\sum _{i=1}^1a_i=a_1$.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that by definition

$$\sum^1_{i=1} 1=1$$

Comment: very nice answer :)

Comment: It was the most deep and difficult for today! :)